# Unable to run mavenized GWT application in eclipse with embedded Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, maven

I have a proof of concept GWT 2.4 / Spring 3.1 / Maven 3 / Eclipse Indigo project that I have been working on. I am able to run the application in Dev Mode using the embedded Jetty server. I am able to create a war (mvn package with help of the `gwt-maven-plugin`)  and run the application on an installed Tomcat server. But when I try to `Run as > Run on Server`, it does not use/copy the generated/compiled JavaScript. When I go to the `wtpwebapps` dir, all is there but the generated/compiled JavaScript. The generated/compiled JavaScript is in the correct location in the maven target dir, it seems, but the eclipse process that copies the code the applcation to the wtpwebapps dir doesn't pick it up.

I'm not sure if I need to give more info to solve this problem, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `com.google.gwt.core.ext.ServletContainerLauncher` using the embedded Tomcat API, or much more simply run your server code in Tomcat (using WTP or the tomcat7-maven-plugin) and then run DevMode in `-noserver` mode.

See https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's

I'm using the second approach in https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes
The archetype uses Jetty for now, but I'm successfully using the tomcat7-maven-plugin on a project based on the archetype (with too many tricks preventing me to set it as the default in the archetype; those tricks only being needed because of the multi-module nature of the project; but there are tricks for Jetty too).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with GWT-dev 2.8.0-beta1 and jetty 9 in my eclipse maven project. Since the GWT-dev jar includes Jetty and other code directly in its jar (which is bad), it conflicts with the jetty I import in my project. The work around was to create a separate module just for running super dev mode, importing GWT-dev and my project's code but excluding the jetty jars. I then run super dev mode via the main below. This way, the super dev mode runs without seeing my jetty libs.

```
import com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer;

public class SuperDevModeMain {

  public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting management-station-web-sdm!");
    String[] options = "-port 9876 com.something.ms.web.MsWeb".split(" ");
    CodeServer.main(options);
  }
}
```